# net core web api: redirecting the post to another post

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

For net core web api projects is it possible to use RedirectToRoute to redirect a post action of a controller to a post action of another one? (I googled it but the responses were a little bit old and stating that only get is allowed for redirection. But I would like be sure that this is still the case.) Thanks.

Comment: Generallt speaking POST requests should not be redirected. There is an http response 307 which can be used for this purpose, but clients may not necessarily support it. Not sure what the situation is as of today, but at least IE used to support it, but with a warning where the user must accept it first.

Comment: Do you mean an "internal" redirect (a controller action call another controller action) or do you mean a redirect executed by the browser ?

Comment: @rboe I mean internal routing, not redirection by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a 307 should do the trick. That can be done using the PreserveMethodRedirect, like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Received(bool status)
{
   return RedirectToActionPreserveMethod("anotherAction");
}
```